# Nuxt 3 How to implement CORS?

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, nuxt3

This is related to my other question about Nuxt 3 security for API's. How do I add CORS? Currently, using the Helmet module is not working for me.

This is the link in my previous question
[Nuxt 3 Prevent Other Wesbsites, Applications, or Domains from accessing my APIs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76197694/nuxt-3-prevent-other-wesbsites-applications-or-domains-from-accessing-my-apis/76197786#76197786)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several ways to implement CORS on your app.

[Method 1.](https://github.com/Baroshem/nuxt-helm)
Using the Nuxt3 Cors Module. This module uses the popular express middleware helmet module.

[Method 2.](https://nuxt.com/modules/security)
Using the security module from Nuxt. More security features added not just the CORS headers.

Method 3.
Manually add CORS using the server middleware.

Here is an example.
`~/server/middleware/cors.ts`

```js
export default defineEventHandler((event) => {
    const headers = {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'Same-Origin',
        'crossOriginResourcePolicy': 'same-origin',
        'crossOriginOpenerPolicy': 'same-origin',
        'crossOriginEmbedderPolicy': 'require-corp',
        'contentSecurityPolicy': "default-src 'self';base-uri 'self';font-src 'self' https: data:;form-action 'self';frame-ancestors 'self';img-src 'self' data:;object-src 'none';script-src 'self';script-src-attr 'none';style-src 'self' https: 'unsafe-inline';upgrade-insecure-requests",
        'X-XSS-Protection': 1
    }
    setHeaders(event, headers)

})
```

Hope that helps you.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, i setup proxy in `nuxt.config.ts`

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    routeRules: {
        '/api/**': {
            proxy: { to: "https:/backend/**" },
         },
    },
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, allow outside people to get login. I do it like this; it works for me:

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    routeRules: {
        '/api/auth/**': {
            cors: true,
         },
    },
}
```